# Rabbitmq: Loaded: not-found; Active: inactive (dead)

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to start the rabbitmq-server using:

```
me@me:~$ sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start
```

...and when I try to check if it is running I get:

```
me@me:~$ sudo systemctl status rabbit-mq-server
● rabbit-mq-server.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

What is the missing file or directory?

Comment: Typo in the `rabbit-mq-server`? Shouldn't it be `rabbitmq-server`? You can always run `systemctl` without any sub-commands and see what services are actually loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, well...I feel really dumb.

```
me@me:~$ sudo systemctl status rabbit-mq-server
```

Should have been:

```
me@me:~$ sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server
```